# Get a point inside the polygon

Tags: geometry

I have a list of points that is a closed path to describe the polygon, how can I get a point that must locate inside the polygon area?
I have no idea with the case of concave polygon,but the average of all the points locate inside the polygon when the case come to convex polygon.

Answer (score 3):

1. Chose first 3 consecutive points from the polygon
2. Check, if the halfway point between the first and the third point is inside the polygon
3. If yes: You found your point
4. If no: Drop first point, add next point and goto 2.

THis is guaranteed to end, as every strictly closed polygon has at least one triangle, that is completly part of the polygon.

For Step 2. search SO, this has been answered many times.

Comment: As it happens, @jimw 's answer has the reference to the lemma, that every strictly closed polygon has at least one triangle "inside" - it is the internal diagonal theorem

Answer (score 3):

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56655/get-a-point-inside-a-polygon

links to:

http://www.exaflop.org/docs/cgafaq/cga2.html#Subject%202.06:%20How%20do%20I%20find%20a%20single%20point%20inside%20a%20simple%20polygon

which says, in part:

```
Given a simple polygon, find some point inside it. Here is a method based on the proof that  
there exists an internal diagonal, in [O'Rourke, 13-14]. The idea is that the midpoint of    
a diagonal is interior to the polygon.

1. Identify a convex vertex v; let its adjacent vertices be a and b.
2. For each other vertex q do:
2a. If q is inside avb, compute distance to v (orthogonal to ab).
2b. Save point q if distance is a new min.
3. If no point is inside, return midpoint of ab, or centroid of avb.
4. Else if some point inside, qv is internal: return its midpoint.
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a summary, the link to exaflop website is dead.