# Place a marker arbitrarily inside a polygon in Google Maps

Tags: algorithm, google-maps, geometry

There is a lot of documentation around how to [detect if a marker is within a polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly) in Google Maps. However, my question is how can I arbitrarily place a marker inside a polygon (ideally as far as possible from the edges)

I tried calculating the average latitude and longitude of the polygon's points, but this obviously fails in some non-concave polygons.

I also thought about calculating the area's [center of mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass), but obviously the same happens.

Any ideas? I would like to avoid [trial-and-error approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797448/get-a-point-inside-the-polygon?rq=1), even if it works 99% of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different ways you could approach this, depending on what exactly you're overall goal is.

One approach would be to construct a *triangulation* of the polygon and place the marker inside one of the triangles. If you're not too worried about optimality you could employ a simple heuristic, like choosing the centroid of the largest triangle, although this obviously wont necessarily give you the point furthest from the polygon edges. There are a number of algorithms for polygon triangulation: [ear-clipping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation) or [constrained Delaunay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) triangulation are probably the way to go, and a number of good libraries exist, i.e. [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/) and [Triangle](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html).

If you are interested in finding an optimal placement it might be possible to use a *skeleton* based approach, using either the [medial-axis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_axis) or the [straight skeleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight_skeleton) of the polygon. The medial-axis is the set of curves equi-distant from the polygon edges, while the straight skeleton is a related structure. Specifically, these type of structures can be used to find points which are furthest away from the edges, [check this out](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc01/professional/papers/pap388/p388.htm) for a label placement application for GIS using an approach based on the straight skeleton.

Hope this helps.